# Property of positive matrix

Tags: matrices, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and let $a = \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2n}\\ 
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & a_{n2}& \dots & a_{nn}\end{pmatrix} \in M_n(A)$ be a **positive** matrix.

Is it true that if $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{C}$, then
$$\begin{pmatrix}\overline{\lambda}_1 & \overline{\lambda}_2 & \dots & \overline{\lambda}_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2n}\\ 
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & a_{n2}& \dots & a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n\end{pmatrix}$$ is a **positive** element of $A$?

I tried using the characterisation $a= x^*x$ but the computation became quite ugly so I was wondering if there is a conceptual easy way to see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a$ is a positive element of $M_n(A)$, then there is a $b \in M_n(A)$ with $a = b^*b$. It follows that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\overline{\lambda}_1 & \overline{\lambda}_2 & \dots & \overline{\lambda}_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2n}\\ 
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & a_{n2}& \dots & a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n\end{pmatrix} = 
\left[b\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n\end{pmatrix} \right]^*\left[b\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n\end{pmatrix}\right].
$$
Now, write
$$
b  \pmatrix{\lambda_1\\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n} = \pmatrix{c_1\\ \vdots \\ c_n}
$$
for some $c_1,\dots,c_n \in A$. From the above, we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\overline{\lambda}_1 & \overline{\lambda}_2 & \dots & \overline{\lambda}_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2n}\\ 
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & a_{n2}& \dots & a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n\end{pmatrix} = 
\pmatrix{c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_n}^* \pmatrix{c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_n} = 
\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^*c_i.
$$
Now, it suffices to note that the sum of positive elements is positive.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give an answer. Why does this imply positivity though?

Comment: Because any element of the form $x^*x$ is positive

Comment: But the latter is a multiplication of a row and column matrix, these elements do not live in the same $C^*$-algebra?

Comment: @user839372 In the algebra $M_n(A) \cong M_n(\Bbb C) \otimes A$

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't quite understand.

Comment: @user839372 I see your issue now. I'll edit appropriately

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @user839372 See my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks! It is clear now!

Comment: Related if you are interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3872321/show-that-xx-is-positive-when-x-in-m-nbh-1-h-2